# Working with zoho api's

Tags: rest, api, get, postman, zoho

I am working on `ZOHO API's`. Using `POSTMAN` I am trying to `GET` the details of a project. The `API` is as follows

```
GET  /portal/[PORTALID]/projects/[PROJECTID]/
Sample Response
Status: 200 Success

Content Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
{
"projects": [{
    "id": 170876000000765009,
    "task_count": {
        "open": 6,
        "closed": 7
    },
    "milestone_count": {
        "open": 2,
        "closed": 1
    },
    "bug_count": {
        "open": 2,
        "closed": 1
    },
    "name": "Website Design Templates",
    "status": "active",
    "created_date": "10-22-2012 02:45 PM",
    "created_date_long": 1350926134092,
    "description": "This project is to discuss different design templates to build a website",
    "owner_name": "Patricia Boyle",
    "owner_id": "2060758",
    "link": {
        "self": {
            "url": "https://projectsapi.zoho.com/restapi/portal/
                    2063927/projects/170876000000765009/"
        },
        "activity": {
            "url": "https://projectsapi.zoho.com/restapi/portal/
                    2063927/projects/170876000000765009/activities/"
        },
        "status": {
            "url": "https://projectsapi.zoho.com/restapi/portal/
                    2063927/projects/170876000000765009/statuses/"
        },
        "milestone": {
            "url": "https://projectsapi.zoho.com/restapi/portal/
                    2063927/projects/170876000000765009/milestones/"
        },
        "tasklist": {
            "url": "https://projectsapi.zoho.com/restapi/portal/
                    2063927/projects/170876000000765009/tasklists/"
        },
        "task": {
            "url": "https://projectsapi.zoho.com/restapi/portal/
                    2063927/projects/170876000000765009/tasks/"
        },
        "bug": {
            "url": "https://projectsapi.zoho.com/restapi/portal/
                    2063927/projects/170876000000765009/bugs/"
        },
        "timesheet": {
            "url": "https://projectsapi.zoho.com/restapi/portal/
                    2063927/projects/170876000000765009/logs/"
        },
        "event": {
            "url": "https://projectsapi.zoho.com/restapi/portal/
                    2063927/projects/170876000000765009/events/"
        },
        "document": {
            "url": "https://projectsapi.zoho.com/restapi/portal/
                    2063927/projects/170876000000765009/documents/"
        },
        "folder": {
            "url": "https://projectsapi.zoho.com/restapi/portal/
                    2063927/projects/170876000000765009/folders/"
        },
        "forum": {
            "url": "https://projectsapi.zoho.com/restapi/portal/
                    2063927/projects/170876000000765009/forums/"
        },
        "user": {
            "url": "https://projectsapi.zoho.com/restapi/portal/
                    2063927/projects/170876000000765009/users/"
        }
    }
}]
}
```

The link is [here](https://www.zoho.com/projects/help/rest-api/projects-api.html#alink2)

But when I try to GET the details. It gives me 404 error. Below is my request.

```
https://bugtracker.zoho.com/portal/fasi/projects/7958751212/
Authentication Token: c1d5c4cfd0bfcfd8b10caf0b174hhh
```

[image]

Moreover, in the link, there is nothing given that how to send the request. All there is sample response.

How can I send a correct request to get the details?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does it help if you remove the trailing `/` from the request? e.g `https://bugtracker.zoho.com/portal/fasi/projects/7958751212` - Failing that, send a request to `GET  /portal/[PORTALID]/projects/` to check that the project Id is the correct one as it may be telling you that it's the wrong number or it's not there at all.

Comment: yes but it doesn't work

Comment: Does your auth token contain the correct scopes? This is an example from the site `https://accounts.zoho.com/apiauthtoken/create?SCOPE=ZohoProjects/projectsapi,ZohoPC/docsapi`

Comment: I was missing `restapi` in the URL so the correct URL format is `https://projectsapi.zoho.com/restapi/portal/2063927/projects`. Now I am able to access it

Comment: Looks like you have basically used a whole new URL and not just added `restapi` to it... :)